# Why can't I access the data field of Point2D in Java?

Tags: java, point

I want to create an array of 100 random points using Point2D. But why can't I access its data field while the data field of Point2D is public? It said "x cannot be resolved or not a field."

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            
    Point2D[] points = new Point2D.Double[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        points[i] = new Point2D.Double();
        points[i].x = Math.random() * 100;
        points[i].y = Math.random() * 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using this class for Point2D: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html

Comment: Yes, I'm using this class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `points` has type `Point2D[]`, therefore `points[i]` has type `Point2D`.  `Point2D` does not have members named `x` or `y`.  The fact that at runtime the *class* of `points[i]` happens to be `Point2D.Double`, which does have such members, is irrelevant to the compiler's analysis.

You could instead declare `points` as

```
    Point2D.Double[] points = new Point2D.Double[100];
```

, or you could use `Point2D.setLocation()` instead of assigning to member variables, as your other answer already suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [setLocation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html#setLocation(double,%20double)). The error-message just says that the compiler doesn't know what .x is supposed to mean on an object of type Point2D.